# Find Related Items Though Tags

Tags: php, mysql

How can i make it into a single MySQL query string to find related items via format "tag1,tag2,tag3"? The above code is a mess and will use too many ressources for this. There may be a better solution.
Thanks

```
$related = [];
$q = mysql_query("select tags from items");
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($q)){
$tags = $row['tags']; //format: tag1,tag2,tag3
$split = explode(",",$tags);

foreach ( $split as $tag):
    $find = mysql_query("select * from items where tags = '".$tag."'");
    $again = mysql_fetch_assoc($find);

    $related[] = $again;
endforeach;

echo "Found related:<br>";
print_r($related);

}
```

Comment: The best solution would be to model a relation between tags and items, not to store tags as simple string values.

Comment: And for the sake of completeness: Please don't use mysql_* function as they a deprecated. use mysqli_* functions/methods instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the mysql find_in_set() function. It works like this.

```
SELECT * FROM items WHERE FIND_IN_SET(tag1,tag2,tag3) > 0;
```

Since your incoming input is already command delimited, all you need to do is add quotes.

```
$tags = $row['tags']; //format: tag1,tag2,tag3
$set = "'".implode("','", $tags)."'";

$sql = "SELECT * FROM items WHERE FIND_IN_SET(" . $set . ") > 0);
```

Comment: So if item has 100 tags, it would show one related if another item only have 20 of the same tags?

Answer (score 0):

You could retrieve them ordered thus removing the need for several queries in your code:

```
SELECT * FROM items ORDER BY tags ASC;
```

You just have to keep track of the previous `tags` so that you know when you start with the next tag.